# libexec folder gone after uninstalling XAMPP on El Capitan

Tags: apache, xampp, osx-elcapitan

I did not know that Apache comes with OSX El Capitan. So I deinstalled XAMPP to start and use the build in apache server.

But after uninstalling XAMPP, my libexec folders are gone also.

How to proceed? Is it save to install XAMPP over it?